# Filing status for two families at one address

Tags: income-tax, missouri

Under US tax law, (for example, in Missouri), are there any special filing considerations for two families with separate qualifying dependents at the same address, if they can provide proof of both families contribute equally to rent, food, and general upkeep?

Consider an adult child, with spouse and children, living with their parents and the parents' other minor children.

Comment: I recommend that you consult a local accountant or tax attorney for specific advice on your situation.  This site is not for specific legal advice.

Comment: I've answered since the general question is a question worth answering, even though it is posed as a request for specific legal advice.

Answer (score 6):

You have two married couples, each of whom have dependents.

More than one family can live at the same address for tax purposes. The analysis would probably be different for census purposes, which collects data on per household basis.